# Unable to use default constructor if user defined constructor is present

Tags: java, debugging, exception, constructor

It seems we are forced to use the user defined constructor if one has been defined and am not able to use the default constructor which has been provided .

I can do this(default constructor) if there is no user defined constructor provided

```
Student s = new student() ;
```

Once a user defined constructor has been provided , I cannot no longer do it , this differs from C++ where i still can use the constructor provided

Sample of code where i defined constructor and unable to do `Student s = new student()`

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;


public class JavaApplication1
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  
        Student s = new Student(); // will get compiler error

        System.out.println(s.getname());


    }

    public static class Student
 {
     private String name;
     private int mark;

     public Student(String namevalue , int markvalue) // user defined constructor
     {
        name = namevalue;
        mark = markvalue;
     }
     public String getname()
     {
         return name;
     }
     public void setname(String value)
     {
         name = value;
     }

 }

}
```

**Is my analysis correct and why is this so ???**

Comment: There is no default constructor provided if you defined your own constructor.

Comment: C++ has the same behaviour!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to understand that the default constructor is only provided by the Java compiler if you fail to provide your own constructor.  The moment you do, you need to provide a no-arg constructor as well. This is confusing to new programmers, but it actually makes a lot of sense if you think about it - do you really want Java to just create things for you without you being in control?

Comment: Thank you to Sotirios for clearing up my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `Student s = new student() ;`, just define a second constructor in your `Stundent`-Class without parameters: 
`public Student() { }`.

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is there for a very good reason.

What if you wanted to prevent developers from accidentally creating a Student without a name and mark? You wouldn't be able to do that if Java always added its own constructor, regardless of whatever constructors you wrote.